# Python Selenium problems with 'for' lusses

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to write a small script in Python using Selenium and Openpyxl to scrape data from a bunch a webpages from one website.

I'm almost there but I still have one problem at the moment. When I run my code the order of the execution of my code is not correct.
The goal is that I read a webpage link from an Excel file that I have, once this is done then the webpage should be opened and then the appropriate data should be scraped. Then this should be repeated for the next webpage until all webpages are scraped.

However what happens is that first all webpages are being opened and then only the last webpage is scraped.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import openpyxl

loc = ("/Users/pierre/Desktop/gegevens.xlsx")
PATH = "/Users/pierre/Downloads/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(loc)
sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name("test")

rows = sheet.max_row
for i in range(1,rows):

    link = (sheet.cell(i,1).value)

    print(link)
    driver.get(link)

for elm1 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mod-article-tile__title"):
    print(elm1.text)

    time.sleep(2)

for elm2 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price__main"):
    print(elm2.text)    

    time.sleep(2)

for elm3 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price__unit"):
    print(elm3.text)  

    time.sleep(2)  

for elm4 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price__base"):
    print(elm4.text) 

    time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```

If anyone can help me this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your indentation

```
for i in range(1,rows):
   link = (sheet.cell(i,1).value)
   print(link)
   driver.get(link)
```

The above code will execute in its entirety before running any of the code below it, because the below code is not considered a part of that for loop.

To complete the action you described, try indenting all this code by one addition tab

```
for elm1 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mod-article-tile__title"):
    print(elm1.text)
    time.sleep(2)
for elm2 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price__main"):
    print(elm2.text)    
    time.sleep(2)
for elm3 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price__unit"):
    print(elm3.text)  
    time.sleep(2)  
for elm4 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price__base"):
    print(elm4.text) 
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for this fast feedback!
I have tried this and this with the following indentation:

```
for i in range(1,rows):
    link = (sheet.cell(i,1).value)
    print(link)
    driver.get(link)
    for elm1 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("mod-article-tile__title"):
        print(elm1.text)
        time.sleep(2)
    for elm2 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price__main"):
        print(elm2.text)    
        time.sleep(2)
    for elm3 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price__unit"):
        print(elm3.text)  
        time.sleep(2)  
    for elm4 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price__base"):
        print(elm4.text) 
        time.sleep(2)  
    driver.quit()
```

But then I get an error saying the following:

File "/Users/pierre/Desktop/Sample.py", line 23
print(elm1.text)
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Yeah, so Python requires you to be consistent about whether you use tabs or spaces to indent. To fix this, since you don't have too many lines -- you should probably just go line by line of code and reindent using only tabs (or only spaces if you prefer).

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to indent driver.quit or the driver will fail after the first 
iteration